# Firebase Android UI Email sign in bad request

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I implemented the new Firebase UI Auth sign in with this code:

```
 startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setTheme(AuthUI.getDefaultTheme())
                    .setProviders(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER)
                    .setTosUrl(GOOGLE_TOS_URL)
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN);
```

last 2 days was working perfectly but now it crashes when entering an email and clicking the "Next" button.

This is the errror:

**com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occured. [ Backend Error ]**

Last point appears to be at

> com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.AcquireEmailHelper$1.onComplete(AcquireEmailHelper.java:57)

I have debugged that point, but there is just no error data.

Anyone have any idea why is this crashing? This happens when creating new users and trying to sign in with existing users too.

I am getting the instructions from :
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: No, nothing yet, problem is that it only happens some times, not every time, lets say 50/50.

Comment: Does whether it crashes or not depend on the email entered?